# How to automatically grab a member's profile photo?

Tags: member, photos, gravatar

I know about gravatar.com, are there any other sites offering similar features?

Thanks

Comment: The title of the question and the body of it seem to differ a lot.

Answer (score 0):

*(Answer to the question posed in the body of the post (not the subject)*)

You'll probably be able to find other providers of services similar to Gravatar. **However**, penetration is likely to be of utmost importance, i.e., you want to use whatever service **most people** use. And that would be Gravatar, AFAIK.

---

For the question posed in the title, see "*[Image Requests](http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/)*."